# How to install GitFlow for Windows

Tags: windows, git, git-flow

Is there a way to install Git Flow on Windows? I tried [this tutorial](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Windows) but I'm unable to understand it.

I already have Git Installed on my PC, can I use GitFlow from my current Git installation?

Comment: For what it's worth, they intend to create an easy installer one day. https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/324

Comment: As you already have git for Windows, you already have msysgit. You can focus on the [msysgit part of the gitflow install tutorial](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Windows#msysgit).

Comment: Alternatively, consider using [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) which comes with built-in GitFlow support.

Comment: Source Tree looks really good. And the GitFlow in it works flawlessly. Thanks.

Comment: @SaadQureshi Hint: Comments can also be upvoted ;-)

Comment: I know, but it seems that I don't have the privilege yet. I need a minimum of 15 reputation for that. I joined 2 days ago BTW.

Comment: is it fork with git-flow implemetation too?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the recently released [Git for Windows 2.5.3](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.5.3.windows.1) which now ships with `git-flow` (the [AVH edition](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh) of it).

Comment: How do you know it's based on AVH edition? I couldn't find any info in the repo about this...

Comment: From the issue tracker, see e.g. https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/536.

Comment: yeah, I just figured `git flow version` shows it too: 1.11.0 (AVH Edition)

Comment: is it fork with git-flow implemetation too?

Answer (score 3):

If you have [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) **OR** if you install Sourcetree, you can find GitFlow options there. This is one of the easiest way to use GitFlow.

[image]

Once you active GitFlow from their (shown in the above screenshot), you can use all GitFlow commands from the terminal as well.